# Android - What are the good reporting tools to design and generate reports from SQLite Data Source?

Tags: android, sqlite, pdf, pdf-generation, reporting

I am working on Android database type application. We need to show some reports.

**My questions are:**

1- How the reporting works on Android?

2- What are the good reporting tools to design and generate reports from SQLite  data source?

3- How to generating pdf type reports from SQLite data source?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no inbuilt reporting framework in Android @Rajdeep also mantioned it in his answer. So now we have these options:

1- Export data to a server, generate the reports on the server & download the reports back to your device.

2- Generate pdf type reports using tools like iText.

I am implementing the 2nd option. Please see this good example of [how to create pdf documents](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPDF/article.html).

Comment: i think that now there is an API for generating reports in Android , check this out :) : http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspermobile-android/releases

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at PDFReporter at www.pdfreporting.com
There is also a open source project "PDFReporter" on sourceforge as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt reporting framework in Android. You will have to write custom code to generate the relevant reports.

One option is to backup the data to a server and use third party reporting tools on it.

Comment: How about generating pdf type reports, it will kill the application performance?

Comment: If your application can make use of an online-service then Docmosis Cloud might help since it can offload the document-generation process so your application has less work to do, but you have latency over networks.

Answer (score 1):

i m still in process of generating report in android... while using iText 5.2 library i have came across so many issues like compatibility betn android and java ...

i think u should generate report in doc format